# PDOException: SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections

Tags: php, database, class, pdo

I'm having an issue with my database; I've been running a site for the past half year and it has been running fine since now, as it's been outputting an error when visiting it:

> Database failed to connect: PDOException: SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too
>   many connections in dbconfig.php:14

I've researched this quite a while but couldn't find a single solution to what may be causing this issue, as it's quite strange how it's popping up after half a year.

My connection code is like this:

```
class Database {
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "[...]";
    private $username = "[...]";
    private $password = "[...]";

    public $conn;

    public function dbConnection() {
        $this->conn = null; 

        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
        } catch(PDOException $exception) {
            exit('Database failed to connect: ' . $exception);
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}
```

What could the issue be? I'm using this code for other sites aswell, so I hope these sites won't be having the same error soon.

Comment: So your website is getting busier with more users and as a result, you are now seeing this message. Depending on your mysql configuration there is a certain limit on how many connections can be open on your db at any one time. To check this limit, run this sql: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections'` check if your db allows you to set this higher. Are you persisting connections in PHP or are you closing them on script execution? It might be worth your while to close them when they are no longer needed. Also, how many db connections does a single user consume in a single session?

Comment: @WebCode.ie Hi, it seems the website is working again (for now?). The website consumes 1 connection per session, and it persists the connection for one hour after inactivity, and then it closes it. I thought it had something to do with my connection code, I am not sure my hosting gives me the option to set max connections, I will be checking with them. (Still weird, since my website isn't really that popular)

Comment: I've executed `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections'` and it's set to 500

Comment: Well, a way around it would be to open and close db connections as you need them. Be wary of search engine and other bots consuming your connections to get the data they need.

Comment: THe answer really depends upon how, when and where you are calling the Database class in your actual code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be destroying the connection unnecessariy in this code. You should be reusing the connection if it has already been made. Also if you have any open statement or results this will not actually close the connection but will open another. This could be your problem. Again it really depends upon how you use this class in your actual scripts. Repeated calls to this within the same script could be causing your problem.

So instead of that reuse it if it has already made a connection. If for no other reason than actually making a connection to tthe database is a comparatively slow process. This is often called a Singleton pattern.

```
class Database {
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "[...]";
    private $username = "[...]";
    private $password = "[...]";

    public $conn = null;

    public function dbConnection() {
        if ( $this->conn !== null ) {
            // already have an open connection so lets reuse it
            return $this->conn;
        }

        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
        } catch(PDOException $exception) {
            exit('Database failed to connect: ' . $exception);
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}
```